# How to comfortably carry equipment when running?

Tags: running

I am a distance runner, and sometimes go running on trails where there aren't likely to be many people. Since I have type-1 diabetes, I must carry a blood glucose tester and a source of quick sugar with me, particularly since exercise can lower blood sugar. While this all amounts to a pretty small amount of equipment, it's more than fits comfortably in the pockets of my running shorts. What are some ways to carry this gear without it impeding running or causing discomfort? We're talking about maybe 200-300g of total mass, though space for a little bit more would not be bad.

Answer (score 15):

[**SPIbelt!**](http://www.spibelt.com/) I don't run without one. They're also frequently used by diabetics as well as runners. They stretch, so they're tiny, but expand to hold a surprisingly large amount of stuff.

[image]

Comment: +1 Definitely worth the money! You can't believe how far this thing will stretch if required

Comment: looks nice but seems to be only available in the US or for very expensive in the UK :-(

Comment: Belts always ride up over my stomach which is pretty uncomfortable and then they flop around.

Comment: @Joe the SPIbelt doesn't bounce! So there really isn't any flopping around. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I use a small camel bag (not too full) for that. Not ideal for reaching the gels but you got liquid as well something you really want on long run.

[image]

Comment: How comfortable are they around the shoulders or do they tend to fit well (so it doesn't sway or rub)?

Comment: @IvoFlipse I personally have a biking edition camelback that I use and it's very comfortable

Comment: While biking that is.

Comment: The body movement when biking is very different from when running though.

Comment: I use it on running as well biking and they are very confortable and fit well.. I have the camelbag branded original version http://is.gd/qgj8Iq

Answer (score 3):

[FuelBelt](http://www.fuelbelt.com/)! It carries water bottles and has various pouches the can hold a gel, a cellphone, or a small camera. I bought the [four-bottle trail-runner model](http://www.fuelbelt.com/s.nl/it.A/id.73/.f?sc=9&category=-109) because of the extra pouches, and in case I ever need all four bottles. I haven't needed more than two bottles, but it's nice to have the option. Instead of a glucose snack or in addition to it, you could have a glucose drink in one bottle. During the summer, I fill one bottle with a sports drink and another bottle with plain water. Each bottle holds 8oz. With four bottles, that's a total of 32oz (1 quart). My belt has two gel pouches, and two zip pouches. My mobile phone easily fits in either of the zipper pouches, and it is comfortable. My only complaint is that my phone tends to make my belt want to rotate slightly, but otherwise, I love it! I don't go running in the heat without it. If you put similar shaped items in the zipper puches, then it won't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

For a jury-rigged setup (if you'd like to get started without spending any money), you can also simply use the belt loop on your shorts.  I attach a climbing hook to my belt loop, tie one end of a string to the hook, and attach the other end to whatever it is I'm carrying.  I used electrical tape to secure my insulin pen, and another knot to secure my water bottle (a 16 oz that I keep in my right pocket).

Answer (score 2):

I personally run with [amphipod's runlite belt](http://www.amphipod.com/products/hydration/hydration-belts/runlite-hydration-belts/runlite-4) with or without the bottles [depends on the length of the run. Has a pouch and a little pocket in the front. Holds my phone, keys, id,

Comment: +1 The combination of a bottle holder and a pocket is pretty decent